# How to get proper format from date for the touch -A argument?

Tags: date, timestamps, touch, macos

I would like to change all of the timestamps of some files to the immediate date.  It appears that I would need to use `touch -A *` (more or less; realizing that I am going to use a more complex form of globbing), however it requires arguments in the following from: `[-][[hh]mm]SS`

How would I coax `date` into providing the properly formatted output to call as an argument from `touch` to accomplish this in the format provided above for `touch`?

Comment: @PM2Ring - OSX `touch` has `-A` ([adjust](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html)). OP, could you elaborate on "immediate date" ? Does that mean current time/date ?

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks. I _think_ the OP wants to set atime and mtime of the selected files to the current time. And if that's so, using `-A` seems like a complicated way to do it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I want to set all time attributes: creation, modification and access to `now`.

Comment: You can't change the ctime of a file using `touch`, only mtime &/or atime. The ctime _can_ be modified, but it's not easy to set it to a time of your choice. See this Stack Exchange question [java.nio.Files - setting “Change time” attribute on a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16126992/4014959) for some info.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to not worry about changing a file's ctime, it's really not worth the hassle (as I discovered myself a month or two ago when writing a script to organize files for simple MP3 players). As well as the methods discussed in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16126992/4014959) I linked to above, there is another straight-forward method: copy the file to a temporary name, delete the original, and then rename the temporary. Of course, that thrashes the disk a fair bit if you want to process a lot of files.

According to the [touch man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) provided above by don_crissti, the purpose of the `-A` option in your version of `touch` is to allow you to apply a **time delta** to the current mtime &/or atime of the file(s). So to use that `-A` option to set the atime and mtime of a file to `now` means that you'd have to calculate the time difference between `now` and the file's existing atime and mtime, which is an unnecessary complication, as I alluded to in my comment.

The easiest way to set the mtime & atime of a set of files to the current time is to simply use touch with its default options. Or, if you want the files to all have *identical* times, touch one file first, and then use that as the reference file on the rest of the files, using touch's `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) for this

```
$ touch -t $(date +%m%d%H%M) file
```

Comment: Close!  But not quite, this works for `-t`, but not `-A`.

Answer (score 0):

The `touch` utility on macOS has a `-A` option that allows you to *adjust* the modification and access timestamps on set of files ("mtime" and "atime" respectively) by a number of hours, minutes and/or seconds.  [In comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164489/how-to-get-proper-format-from-date-for-the-touch-a-argument#comment271087_164489), you appear to want to *set* the timestamps to the current time, not adjust them.  The `-A` option would therefore be the wrong option to use.

To change the mtime and atime timestamps on a set of files to the current time, use

```
touch -c pattern
```

where `pattern` is some pattern that matches the files you'd like to touch.  The `-c` option makes sure that you don't create files if the pattern does not match, or if you provide an explicit list of files that contains nonexistent names.

As a side effect of modifying the mtime and atime timestamps, the ctime timestamp ("inode change timestamp") will also be modified.

To set the btime ("birth timestamp", which *may* be what you call the "creation timestamp" [in your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164489/how-to-get-proper-format-from-date-for-the-touch-a-argument/554989#comment271087_164489)), you may want to use the (deprecated) `SetFile` command, which is used to "set attributes of files and directories" on macOS.

```
SetFile -d "$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')" pattern
```

Use `SetFile` with the same datestamp string with the `-m` option to update the mtime.  Setting the btime or mtime in this manner also updates the ctime of the file.  The `SetFile` utility does not/can not update the atime timestamp.